# Which row has the highest value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table of election results for multiple nominees and polls. I need to determine which nominee had the most votes for each poll.

Here's a sample of the data in the table:

```
PollID  NomineeID   Votes
1       1           108
1       2           145
1       3           4
2       1           10
2       2           41
2       3           0
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions or help anyone can offer me.

Comment: Which database are you using (the answer varies between them)

Comment: First, I would `sum(votes)`, grouped by `NomineeId, PollId`. Then work on this result set to keep only the `Nominee` which has the max votes.

Comment: @Bohemian - I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 3):

This will match the highest, and will also bring back ties.

```
select sd.*
from sampleData sd
    inner join (
        select PollID, max(votes) as MaxVotes
        from sampleData
        group by PollID
    ) x on
        sd.PollID = x.PollID and
            sd.Votes = x.MaxVotes
```

Comment: Requires inner join. I think RANK() will have better performance. Maybe CTE would be also better.

Comment: +1 for not using sqlserver specific code. This will work in most (all?) database flavours

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  t.NomineeID,
  t.PollID
FROM 
  ( SELECT
      NomineeID,
      PollID, 
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.PollID ORDER BY i.Votes DESC) AS Rank
    FROM SampleData i) t
WHERE 
  t.Rank = 1
```

Comment: The same nominee can be listed for multiple polls.  This query won't tell the user which poll the nominee won for.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will be adding "RANK" to my toolbox.

Comment: You are welcome. Cannot find a better solution. CTE (good thing to learn) will be worse in this case.

Comment: @Pellared what? Can you explain why "CTE will be worse in this case"?

Comment: I was thinking of a similar solution to Bill's using CTE but that would also require a join.

Comment: Now that you've corrected it, I've removed my -1.  That's how it's supposed to work.  I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PollID, NomineeID, Votes
FROM 
table AS ABB2
    JOIN
       (SELECT PollID, MAX(Votes) AS most_votes
        FROM table) AS ABB1 ON ABB1.PollID = ABB2.PollID AND ABB1.most_votes = ABB2.Votes
```

Please note, if you have 2 nominees with the same number of most votes for the same poll, they'll both be pulled using this query

Answer (score 0):

```
select Pollid, Nomineeid, Votes from Poll_table 
where Votes in ( 
    select max(Votes) from Poll_table 
    group by Pollid
);
```